# Samba 2.2.12 accepts my password, but is rejecting other user accounts?

Tags: freebsd, windows, samba

I'm using a legacy system and I'm stuck with FreeBSD 5.4 and Samba 2.2.12, trying to access it from a Windows 7 system.

I've created a unix account in FreeBSD using the `adduser` command and added myself to a group that allows read write access to a shared location. I then created a Samba account for myself using the `smbpasswd -a <user>` command.

When I map a network drive to this account under Win 7, I check the "Connect using different credentials" option in the Map Network Drive dialog and provide the Samba username and password to the password challenge. The system accepts it and maps the drive to my account.

When I follow the above procedure to create another user however, every time I provide the account name and password, it rejects the credentials and comes back with another password challenge dialog and won't map to the drive. I've run through the procedure several times and I'm pretty sure that the username and password are correct.

I'm not sure why it is doing this and I was wondering if somehow my Windows 7 login is influencing my Samba account. It is a bit odd if it does, because besides my full name being associated with the accounts, the unix/samba account has a different username from my Windows account.

The content of smb.conf is detailed below, with some changes here and there to retain anonymity.

```
# This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
# smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
# here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options (perhaps too
# many!) most of which are not shown in this example
#
# Any line which starts with a ; (semi-colon) or a # (hash) 
# is a comment and is ignored. In this example we will use a #
# for commentry and a ; for parts of the config file that you
# may wish to enable
#
# NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command "testparm"
# to check that you have not many any basic syntactic errors. 
#
#======================= Global Settings =====================================
[global]

# workgroup = NT-Domain-Name or Workgroup-Name, eg: REDHAT4
   workgroup = EAGLE

# server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field
   server string = EAGLE systems

# This option is important for security. It allows you to restrict
# connections to machines which are on your local network. The
# following example restricts access to two C class networks and
# the "loopback" interface. For more examples of the syntax see
# the smb.conf man page
;   hosts allow = 192.168.1. 192.168.2. 127.

# If you want to automatically load your printer list rather
# than setting them up individually then you'll need this
   load printers = no

# you may wish to override the location of the printcap file
;   printcap name = /etc/printcap

# on SystemV system setting printcap name to lpstat should allow
# you to automatically obtain a printer list from the SystemV spool
# system
;   printcap name = lpstat

# It should not be necessary to specify the print system type unless
# it is non-standard. Currently supported print systems include:
# bsd, sysv, plp, lprng, aix, hpux, qnx
;   printing = bsd

# Uncomment this if you want a guest account, you must add this to /etc/passwd
# otherwise the user "nobody" is used
;  guest account = pcguest

# this tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
# that connects
   log file = /var/log/log.%m

# Put a capping on the size of the log files (in Kb).
   max log size = 50

# Security mode. Most people will want user level security. See
# security_level.txt for details.
   security = user

# Use password server option only with security = server
# The argument list may include:
#   password server = My_PDC_Name [My_BDC_Name] [My_Next_BDC_Name]
# or to auto-locate the domain controller/s
#   password server = *
;   password server = <NT-Server-Name>

# Note: Do NOT use the now deprecated option of "domain controller"
# This option is no longer implemented.

# You may wish to use password encryption. Please read
# ENCRYPTION.txt, Win95.txt and WinNT.txt in the Samba documentation.
# Do not enable this option unless you have read those documents
  encrypt passwords = yes

# Using the following line enables you to customise your configuration
# on a per machine basis. The %m gets replaced with the netbios name
# of the machine that is connecting
;   include = /usr/local/etc/smb.conf.%m

# Most people will find that this option gives better performance.
# See speed.txt and the manual pages for details
# You may want to add the following on a Linux system:
#         SO_RCVBUF=8192 SO_SNDBUF=8192
   socket options = TCP_NODELAY 

# Configure Samba to use multiple interfaces
# If you have multiple network interfaces then you must list them
# here. See the man page for details.
;   interfaces = 192.168.12.2/24 192.168.13.2/24 
   interfaces = 180.207.29.26/24

# Browser Control Options:
# set local master to no if you don't want Samba to become a master
# browser on your network. Otherwise the normal election rules apply
   local master = no

# OS Level determines the precedence of this server in master browser
# elections. The default value should be reasonable
;   os level = 33

# Domain Master specifies Samba to be the Domain Master Browser. This
# allows Samba to collate browse lists between subnets. Don't use this
# if you already have a Windows NT domain controller doing this job
   domain master = no

# Preferred Master causes Samba to force a local browser election on startup
# and gives it a slightly higher chance of winning the election
   preferred master = no

# Enable this if you want Samba to be a domain logon server for 
# Windows95 workstations. 
   domain logons = no

# if you enable domain logons then you may want a per-machine or
# per user logon script
# run a specific logon batch file per workstation (machine)
;   logon script = %m.bat
# run a specific logon batch file per username
;   logon script = %U.bat

# Where to store roving profiles (only for Win95 and WinNT)
#        %L substitutes for this servers netbios name, %U is username
#        You must uncomment the [Profiles] share below
;   logon path = \\%L\Profiles\%U

# Windows Internet Name Serving Support Section:
# WINS Support - Tells the NMBD component of Samba to enable it's WINS Server
;   wins support = yes

# WINS Server - Tells the NMBD components of Samba to be a WINS Client
#   Note: Samba can be either a WINS Server, or a WINS Client, but NOT both
;   wins server = w.x.y.z

# WINS Proxy - Tells Samba to answer name resolution queries on
# behalf of a non WINS capable client, for this to work there must be
# at least one  WINS Server on the network. The default is NO.
   wins proxy = no

# DNS Proxy - tells Samba whether or not to try to resolve NetBIOS names
# via DNS nslookups. The built-in default for versions 1.9.17 is yes,
# this has been changed in version 1.9.18 to no.
   dns proxy = no 

# Client codepage settings

# for Greek users
; client code page=737

# for European users (Latin 1)
; client code page=850

# for European users (Latin 2)
; client code page=852

# for Icelandic users
; client code page=861

# for Cyrillic users
; client code page=866

# for Japanese Users
; client code page=932
; coding system=cap

# for Simplified Chinese Users
; client code page=936
; coding system=cap

# for Korean Users
; client code page=949
; coding system=cap

# for Traditional Chinese Users
; client code page=950
; coding system=cap

#============================ Share Definitions ==============================
[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = no
   writeable = yes
# Un-comment the following two lines to add a recycle bin facility to a samba share
# NOTE: It currently doesn't work with the [homes] virtual share, use a regular share instead
;  vfs object = /usr/local/lib/samba/recycle.so
;  vfs options= /usr/local/etc/recycle.conf.default

# Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons
; [netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /usr/local/samba/lib/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
;   writeable = no
;   share modes = no


# Un-comment the following to provide a specific roving profile share
# the default is to use the user's home directory
;[Profiles]
;    path = /usr/local/samba/profiles
;    browseable = no
;    guest ok = yes


# NOTE: If you have a BSD-style print system there is no need to 
# specifically define each individual printer
;[printers]
;   comment = All Printers
;   path = /var/spool/samba
;   browseable = no
;# Set public = yes to allow user 'guest account' to print
;   guest ok = no
;   writeable = no
;   printable = yes

# This one is useful for people to share files
;[tmp]
;   comment = Temporary file space
;   path = /tmp
;   read only = no
;   public = yes

# A publicly accessible directory, but read only, except for people in
# the "Bird" group.
# New files/directories put in group Bird, and group write permission added.
[BIRD_disk]
   comment = The nesting place.
   path = /BIRD_disk
   browseable = yes
   public = no
   writeable = yes
   printable = no
   write list = @Bird
   force group = +Bird
   force create mode = 0775
   force directory mode = 0775

# Other examples. 
#
# A private printer, usable only by fred. Spool data will be placed in fred's
# home directory. Note that fred must have write access to the spool directory,
# wherever it is.
;[fredsprn]
;   comment = Fred's Printer
;   valid users = fred
;   path = /homes/fred
;   printer = freds_printer
;   public = no
;   writeable = no
;   printable = yes

# A private directory, usable only by fred. Note that fred requires write
# access to the directory.
;[fredsdir]
;   comment = Fred's Service
;   path = /usr/somewhere/private
;   valid users = fred
;   public = no
;   writeable = yes
;   printable = no

# a service which has a different directory for each machine that connects
# this allows you to tailor configurations to incoming machines. You could
# also use the %U option to tailor it by user name.
# The %m gets replaced with the machine name that is connecting.
;[pchome]
;  comment = PC Directories
;  path = /usr/pc/%m
;  public = no
;  writeable = yes

# A publicly accessible directory, read/write to all users. Note that all files
# created in the directory by users will be owned by the default user, so
# any user with access can delete any other user's files. Obviously this
# directory must be writeable by the default user. Another user could of course
# be specified, in which case all files would be owned by that user instead.
;[public]
;   path = /usr/somewhere/else/public
;   public = yes
;   only guest = yes
;   writeable = yes
;   printable = no
# Un-comment the following two lines to add a recycle bin facility to a samba share
;  vfs object = /usr/local/lib/samba/recycle.so
;  vfs options= /usr/local/etc/recycle.conf.default

# The following two entries demonstrate how to share a directory so that two
# users can place files there that will be owned by the specific users. In this
# setup, the directory should be writeable by both users and should have the
# sticky bit set on it to prevent abuse. Obviously this could be extended to
# as many users as required.
;[myshare]
;   comment = Mary's and Fred's stuff
;   path = /usr/somewhere/shared
;   valid users = mary fred
;   public = no
;   writeable = yes
;   printable = no
;   create mask = 0765
```

Comment: When you provide the username/password to access the share are you specifying a windows domain such as `mysambaserver\user1`? Also what do the Samba logs show you when you're authentication fails?

Comment: I left it as the default domain, i.e., `AU`, that is displayed at the password challenge dialog. Even when I add that domain to the login name as you suggested, I am still getting the same results that I reported in my question, i.e., can login with my account but not others. Oddly enough the workgroup setting specified in the `smb.conf` is different from `AU`. I also tried to login using the domain indicated in `smb.conf` but that fails for all users, including me. I inspected the log in the `/var/log/log.mymachine` but it does not even seem to create an entry for a successful or failed login

Comment: What is the config of the share? Can we see it? Also are all the clients the same I mean Windows 7 systems?

Comment: also check your share policy in the clients and compare with the working one: Local Computer - Policy->Computer Configuration->Windows Settings->Security Settings->Local Policies->Security Options, the value Microsoft network client: Digitally sign communications.
I believe that in the working one this might be disable and in the non working set as always. Give it a try.

Comment: Please share the `smb.conf`.

Comment: @BitsOfNix: I've been trying to map to the share from my client machine only so it would be just Windows 7. I had a look at the share policy you mentioned and it is set to disabled. I have provided the content of smb.conf as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Windows does not allow multiple connections to a shared resource by the same user and using different usernames → http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938120

Some suggested workaround can be found here → https://superuser.com/questions/95872/sambawindows-allow-multiple-connections-by-different-users

Took me a while to figure this out because sometimes the Windows 7 client just throws another password challenge dialog even though you just provided the correct credentials, and sometimes it displays the error dialog indicating that multiple connections by the same user are not allowed.